# SDL está sempre gerando tela transparente. c++

Tags: c++, sdl

criei e compilei um programa em SDL, não sei o motivo, mas ele sempre retorna uma tela transparente, quando o esperado é uma tela branca.

[image: Resultado do SDL]

Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Surface *screenSurface;
    
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tutorial", 100, 50, 320, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    
    SDL_FreeSurface(screenSurface);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    
    return 0;

}
```

E estou compilando com este comando no cmd:

```
g++ "C:\Users\DANI\Documents\Learn\SDL\Test.cpp" -o Test.exe -I "C:\MinGW\include\SDL2" -mwindows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Answer (score 0):

Para desenhar na janela temos de usar o SDL_Renderer. A função SDL_RenderClear preenche o background.

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Tutorial", 100, 50, 320, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_FreeSurface(screenSurface);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```